# Installed OS Language with Language Pack installed?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mui

When the user has an en-US Windows 7 version, the "CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture" function reports back en-US even when you have installed a different language pack (such as nl-NL). Is there a .NET/PInvoke method to get the language the current user is actually using (preferably as a CultureInfo class)? I also can't rely on the CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture as this can be changed by the user.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks John, didn't know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "GetUserDefaultUILanguage" with:

CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(GetUserDefaultUILanguage());